# Running a matlab mfile on a remote cluster

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, gpu

I am solving a nonlinear partial differential equation in Matlab. My code calls the fft2 and ifft2 commands many times. So I want to use a GPU of a cluster to speed up the computations. I have prepared my codes for gpu using gpuArray and gather. However, I am quite naive in cluster using and the only thing I know is that I should use an ssh terminal using putty and Matlab is not installed on the cluster and my codes need to be compiled first.
1st of all I would like to know how I should compile my Matlab codes
And 2nd, how to run this code on this remote cluster? what are the commands?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to utilize the GPU you need to change `fft2(x)` into `gather(fft2(gpuArray(x)))`. Similarly, `ifft2(x)` becomes `gather(ifft2(gpuArray(x)))`.

Assuming you're not talking about using the cluster as a worker for parallel computation, you can run MATLAB commands from a linux terminal using a command of the form `matlab -r 'myfunction'`. Note that `myfunction.m` must exist in the current working directory or MATLAB's default path.

Once you've modified your script to use the GPU, ssh into the cluster, change to the directory containing your script and run `matlab -r` command.

Comment: Jodag
Thanks for the answer. I just found out that MATLAB is not installed on the cluster. I edited the question above. Do you have an idea? myfunction.m exists on the cluster (I used filezilla to copy my files there) and my codes do not use any parallel computation.

Comment: You can't run MATLAB on the cluster if its not installed on the cluster.